Laravel Jetstream: How to add cookies to store login information with laravel jetstrem on laravel 11
I want to store cookies after the user logs in for the client to use, but when I use laravel jetstream, I don't know how to add cookies after logging in.
Note that I am trying to use two different interfaces to display data so saving a cookie that identifies the user is necessary.
I tried searching for it on google but didn't get any results. I also tried adding a middleware to JetstreamServiceProvider but it didn't work.
Can someone please help me?

similar to the middleware method you have tried, checking the Jetstream docs (https://jetstream.laravel.com/features/authentication.html#customizing-the-authentication-pipeline) you can do something similar by attaching your custom class to the authentication pipeline.
On the boot method of App\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider:
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\AttemptToAuthenticate;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\PrepareAuthenticatedSession;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

Fortify::authenticateThrough(function (Request $request) {
    return array_filter([
            config('fortify.limiters.login') ? null : EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled::class,
            RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable::class,
            AttemptToAuthenticate::class,
            PrepareAuthenticatedSession::class,
            SetCookieAfterAuthentication::class,
    ]);
});

// cookie class:
...

public function __invoke(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $next)
{
    $name = 'name';
    // some conditional value
    $value = $request->user()->condition ? "val1" : "val2";
    $minutes = 15;
    Cookie::queue($name, $value, $minutes);

    return $next($request);
}


@qnjoong was this answer usefull?
